# ApplePay issue - Payment not Completed

Tags: ios, swift, applepay

After creating PKPaymentRequest I try to make a payment and always get the same error on the UI - Payment not completed. The delegate method is never called so I could not even understand what is the problem.
Initializing PKPayemntRequest is:

```
request.merchantIdentifier = "MY MERCHANT ID"
request.countryCode = countryCode
request.currencyCode = currency
request.supportedNetworks = [.visa, .masterCard, .amex]
if #available(iOS 12.0, *) { request.supportedNetworks.append(.maestro) }
request.paymentSummaryItems = [PKPaymentSummaryItem(label: "Transaction text", amount: NSDecimalNumber(decimal: amount))]
request.merchantCapabilities = .capabilityCredit
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you must support 3DS; support of EMV is optional.

Like:

```
request.merchantCapabilities = PKMerchantCapabilityEMV | PKMerchantCapability3DS;
```

Comment: After setting merchantCapabilities with this array [.capability3DS, .capabilityEMV, .capabilityCredit] everything is working like a charm! 

Thank you very much!